# PHP Returning a value from and use methods on it

Tags: php, function, methods, return

So , i have this function which returns a result set :

```
function get_products()
{
    global $database;
    $statement = 'select * from products';
    return $result = $database->query($statement);
}
```

and i want to call it in other php file like this :

```
include './DBvalidation.php';
   $res = get_products();
   $res->fetchAll();
```

but the method fetchAll() of the return set is not recognized there . what should i modify ?

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_products()
{
    global $database;
    $statement = 'select * from products';
    return $database->query($statement);
}
```

OR:

```
function get_products()
{
    global $database;
    $statement = 'select * from products';
    $result = $database->query($statement);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much ! it works , i don't know why they unvoted you

Answer (score 1):

You cant just use the `$result` assosiation as return statement (it will just return `true` in Your case, which is wrong) use something like this instead :

```
return $database->query($statement);
```

You dont even need the `$result` variable at all anyway cause its end of function execution and You wont be able to use it elsewhere.